# Proboscis Not Skipping Tests With depends_on_group

Tags: python-2.7, saucelabs, proboscis

I have a test class which runs in SauceLabs and I know that the first test fails. What I am trying to do is to get it to not run tests 2-5 if test one fails. I have Proboscis up and working with it and it is launching the tests, it just is not skipping the tests 2-5 if test one fails.

Just wondering if anyone has seen this before and how you handled it?

Yes I have read the documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/proboscis/#downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem we were experiencing is due to a really dumb limitation with Proboscis. That limitation is that if you are using `self` it ignores the decorators.

We used built-in functionality in `unittest` and `nosetest` to do what we needed to do.

In our `setup` method we added the following line:

```
def setUp(self):
    **self.skip_after_fail = True**
    BaseService.setUp(self)
```

The test cases have to be named in a specific order for instance:

```
def test_1_method(self):
def test_2_method(self):
def test_2_method(self):
```

Then if test_1 fails the others will be skipped.